# Proper way to align list with colon separated values

Tags: usability, gui-design, interaction-design, user-behavior, interface

I am creating a very small list of data for a device which will be displayed on an overlay. The following format is as follows: [image]

There are many different ways these items can be aligned and I've created a few of them here.
[image]
Is there any benefit to picking one alignment over another?

Comment: Is keeping the colon a requirement? If not, it might be useful to work with different font weights and colors instead.

Comment: @LeoWattenberg Not necessarily. So if there's no colon, how should the left and right column be aligned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do either. But test if you can to validate.

A very common (and fairly safe) pattern is a left algned bold **Label**, and a left aligned value in a regular weight.

[image]

You can do right aligned, but here's a thought from designer leader LukeW, in his book **[Web form design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933820241)**. Note the bold text in the quote.

Granted, he's talking about forms, but you also have label-value pairs, just in a static state.

He writes that in **forms:**

> Right-aligned labels also have the advantage of
> close proximity between input field and label
> and, as a result, are quick to complete (see
> Figure 4.6). ***The resulting left rag of the labels
> in a right-aligned layout, however, reduces
> the effectiveness of a quick scan to see what
> information the form requires. In the Western
> world, people read from left to right, so their
> eyes prefer a hard edge along the left side.***

It's easy to scan the labels when they are left aligned. There's also no need for a colon if it's not part of the value. It just adds extra visual noise.

Answer (score 0):

Another format to consider...

[image: label right format small italic]

Here the label is to the right of the value and formatted to be referential but not detract from the value it refers to.

Here's why...

The **primary purpose** in a block of information such as this is to **locate and read the value**. The only purpose of the label is to locate the value. Giving emphasis to the value allows, with experience, *internalization of the location* of particular values, reducing and *even eliminating the need to cognitively process the label*.

The difference between a block of information and a form is in the form the value is undetermined—*there's no value expressed* to help identify the type of the value, so the label is an essential part of determining a type value. Whereas **a block of information has the values, and in many cases the type is self-evident**.

The label is not always necessary to locate the value. In this example, the *Last Reported* date value is distinctive—the type of value is self-evident and the user quickly learns what kind of date it refers to and thereafter does not need to use label. Even the *Serial Number* and *IMEI*, although similar constructs, the user will learn, with use, the *Serial Number* is first and *IMEI* is second.

The technique here is to de-emphasize the label:

1. Place after the value.
2. Make the font smaller.
3. Italicize.

Other options:

[image: label right formal small parens]

[image: label right format small]

[image: label right format small ghost]